# Windows Azure + Asp.Net MVC + E-Commerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, e-commerce

I will developp and host an e-commerce website based on Asp.Net MVC4 (with several SQL Server Jobs).

I think use Azure in order to stay in Microsoft's world and avoid dedicated server management.

The package Web Site Shared with 1 site / 5Go SQL Server Database / 200Go Bandwidth is very interesting with the price based on 12 months.

But i don't know if this configuration is enough specially on the bandwidth.

What do you think of ? Did you use Azure with this type of application ?

Regards,
Guillaume.

Comment: try out [VirtoCommerce](http://virtocommerce.com) enterprise open source product, open source is available at Codeplex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to develop E-Commerce application you will have to secure customers' sensitive data i.e. credit cards, address details etc. via secure connections (**HTTPS; in many countries this is legal requirement**). For that reason you will have to have SSL support.

**Azure Website** do not support SSL for custom domains. However, they support SSL for **.azurewebsites.net* DNS name. So if your E-Commerce application DNS will be, say, *my-ecom-app.azurewebsites.net* then it's fine. Otherwise, I would not recommend Azure Website solution yet (I am sure SSL support for custom domains on Azure Website will be implemented).

**Azure Cloud Services**, on the other had, have full support of SSL for custom domains.

One of the really good websites to check Azure features and development roadmap is [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/)

Comment: On top of this, (for the UK at least) you need to ensure you are PCI compliant, if you will be handling consumer credit transations.
www.pcicomplianceguide.org

Comment: Indeed the lack of SSL on custom domain is a real problem. And i read that Azure does not support SQL Server Jobs and i need it. Thanks for all your replies.

Comment: @rg701653 you're right. Azure SQL does not support server jobs. But that can change in the future. If you watch ScottGu's Blog (link in my answer) you will get details about all new coming features. SSL support for Azure Website is on the roadmap but it is not that high priority at this moment.

Comment: Appharbor.com supports SSL for custom domains if you want a .NET PAAS. In fact, this is the reason why we have chosen Appharbor over Azure for our application.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Web Sites do not support SSL and I really don't know of any successful e-commerce site that does not run SSL for at least part of the website. If you really want to host your e-commerce on Azure today your only real choice is to run Virtual Machines for your web front end servers and use them for your DB or use SQL Azure.

Answer (score 0):

We developed platform called [Virto Commerce](http://virtocommerce.com) that does just that, MVC4 website hosted on Azure. There was also a need for SQL Jobs (indexing, payment processing, cart cleanups and so on) for which we used WorkerRole (instead of WebRole). WorkerRole and WebRole can actually be combined as part of a single deployment, however it is better to use a different instance for worker roles. In our case WorkerRole acted as a scheduler for multiple jobs defined in the database.

The challenge with WorkerRoles however is to make sure they scale well when new instances are added. So the workload needs to be distributed between multiple instances. This is done through the use of queues and blob locks, where each job is now split into two, one that schedules and partitions the work and the second that actually picks up the next partition and completes it.

Hope this helps!

PS: Virto Commerce is now available as an open source project on codeplex, go to http://virtocommerce.codeplex.com